# ASP.NET MVC 6 Angular JS Table Update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently learning new MVC 6 and stucked completely with simple action - table data update on item selection change.The desired behaviour is to load questions that belong selected question block

I have angularJS factory:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('questionBlockApp')
        .factory('questionBlockService', questionBlockService);

    var questionBlockService = angular.module('questionBlockService', ['ngResource']);

    questionBlockService.factory('Blocks', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/blocks/', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
        });
    }]);

    questionBlockService.factory('Questions', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/blocks/:blockId', {blockId : '@blockId'}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
        });
    }]);

})();
```

Controller, which has refresh func (loadQuestions) built inside selection change function:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('questionBlockApp')
        .controller('questionBlockController', questionBlockController);
        //.controller('questionController', questionController);

    questionBlockController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Blocks', 'Questions'];
    //questionController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Questions'];

    function questionBlockController($scope, Blocks, Questions) {
        $scope.selectedBlock = 2;

        if ($scope.Blocks == undefined | $scope.Blocks == null) {
            $scope.Blocks = Blocks.query();
        }

        $scope.setSelected = function (blockId) {
            $scope.selectedBlock = blockId;
            $scope.loadQuestions();
        }
     
        $scope.loadQuestions = function () {
            $scope.data = Questions.query({ blockId: $scope.selectedBlock });
            $scope.data.$promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.Questions = data;
            });
        };

        $scope.loadQuestions();
    }

})();
```

And views:

View from which setSelected is called:

```html
 <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" ng-cloak ng-controller="questionBlockController">
                <thead>
                  ...
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="block in Blocks" ng-click="setSelected(block.Id)" ng-class="{'selected': block.Id == selectedBlock}">
                        <td>{{block.Id}}</td>
                        <td>{{block.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{block.Created}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

```html
 <table id="test" ng-controller="questionBlockController">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            ...
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="question in Questions">
                            <td>{{question.Id}}</td>
                            <td>{{question.Text}}</td>
                            <td>{{question.TimeLimit}}</td>
                            <td>{{question.Updated}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

When I click on different items in QuestionBlock table, $scope.Questions is updated properly, but the table does not reflect changes, as if no binding exists.

Comment: so this always shows data related to `selectedBlock = 2` rt ?? or where you are binding `ng-click` directive to call `setSelected` function ??

Comment: Y, sry, it is ng-click is in another table, which presents question blocks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am just a bit damaged. 
There are two `questionBlockController` controllers defined, leading to intialization of different scopes => two `$scope.Questions` objects existence => refresh occured in Blocks scope, which was undesired behaviour.